# Что не верно в этй строке?

Tags: php

При sumbit-е кнопки в обратной форме сайт выдает такую ошибку:

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/content/86/11937486/html/pazroof/submitQuote.php on line 47

```
function validateEmail($email)
{
   if(eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$', $email)) - лайн 47
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: `eregi` заменить на `preg_match`. Ну и само регулярное выражение изменить. Либо изменить версию php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eregi - функция устарела (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eregi.php). Можно заменить на preg_match (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Тоесть мне нуно просто eregi заменить на preg_matchi? Простите за глупые вопросы, совсем не знаю языка Php. Переделываю чей-то косяк

Comment: Посмотрите документацию по ссылке (там очень хорошо описано), не хотелось бы просто копипастить